# hdpi device choosing mdpi images

Tags: android, hdpi, mdpi

I'm new to android. Trying to figure out why this is happening with this: I have an image in a `hdpi drawable` folder that is not getting used. It's 1.5 times greater in size than the `mdpi` image both with the same name. I have a different layout for each resolution. Can someone help me understand why the `mdpi` image is the only one getting used? I've already checked the other stackoverflow threads on this and the android developer documents and I can't find an answer as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us some code, layouts and/or your res-folder directory layout, so we better can help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply, found a solution.

Comment: Please post your solution and accept it to help others who might come across this problem

Comment: Probably not worth a full post. I had not appropriately named the layout folders for the corresponding screen densities. :\